# How to run DocFetcher as a background process

Tags: process, services, search-indexing, file-server

Can somebody help with running DocFetcher as a background process or windows service, so it can index files without logging in to a file server?

http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html

Comment: I read in another post that I should edit the batch file to show all exact paths.

Comment: cd %~dp0

set libclasspath=

for %%f in (.\lib\*.jar) do (call :append_classpath %%f)
goto :proceed

:append_classpath
set libclasspath=%libclasspath%;%1
goto :eof

:proceed
java -enableassertions -Xmx512m -Xss2m -cp %libclasspath% -Djava.library.path=lib net.sourceforge.docfetcher.Main %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9

Answer (score 0):

Within the [link](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/en/index.html) you shared, the section on **Index Updates** states:

> ...DocFetcher is capable of automatically updating its indexes: (1)
>   When it's running, it detects changed files and updates its indexes
>   accordingly. (2) When it isn't running, *a small daemon in the
>   background will detect changes and keep a list of indexes to be
>   updated; DocFetcher will then update those indexes the next time it is
>   started.*

The software seems to cover what you need without additional configuration - unless you need the indexes updated immediately and not when the app starts again?

Comment: The file server has nobody logging in to it. It is just a central mapped data drive on a LAN. 1) won't work because the DocFetcher.exe program will not update the index unless somebody logs in and starts it. 2) The daemon is running as a start up program which is good, but once again the DocFetcher.exe program has to be started to index the file changes recorded by the daemon.

Answer (score 0):

According to [docs](http://docfetcher.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=tips_tricks#updating_indexes_from_the_command-line)

> To update all indexes from the command-line, start the DocFetcher executable with the --update-indexes parameter.

Add a task to Windows scheduler to run on computer boot with command `docfetcher --update-indexes`

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason it does not seem to work without logging in and doing it manually using  the command prompt. Is someody able to confirm?

Comment: I had Task Scheduler security option set to "Run whether user is logged on or not"....I found out that it will only work if I am logged in and have the security option set to "Run only when user is logged in", but that sort of defeats the purpose of setting up a Task Scheduler to run when not around to log in. Any way to fix this?

Comment: My problem seems identical to this one:       https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25752296/task-scheduler-cannot-open-batch-file-when-set-to-run-whether-user-is-logged-on